# How can I build a route and access its coordinates?

Tags: swift, mapkit, core-location, watchkit

I'm writing an app on watchKit. My aim is to build a route between two points but I do not imagine how could I do it. On the iPhone MapKit does it for you, but can I do something similar in the watches? Can I access the route (array of CLLocation coordinates maybe) which is built on the iPhone MapKit?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have an app running on the Apple Watch.  Your app will run in an WatchKit extension running on your iPhone.  In your WatchKit extension you can use MapKit to create a route.  The difference is that you will need to display your map using `WKInterfaceMap` in your watch app.  `WKInterfaceMap` only allows annotations with images and pins, so I don't think you can display a route on the map, though I am not sure.  I have an outdoors mapping application, but I rolled my own tile renderer which allows me to display routes on the watch.

Comment: hey Stephen would you mind elaborating on how you displayed routes on the watch?

Comment: I did not use MapKit to do my routes.  I have my own map view that I built.  It has the ability to draw maps and overlay images and points from coordinates.  You can probably find something that will do this for you, though I am not sure.  You could probably modify the open source MapBox code to do that as well.

Comment: Hey, I just wondered if you'd considered making your code for routes on watchOS maps open-source? Or perhaps an article about how to make your own tile renderer?